# playing video works on simulator but not on ipad (2)

Tags: apache-flex, ipad, video, air, flex-mobile

I have been trying to play a video that was converted using http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/ to mp4 file , it is woking fine on the simulator but on the ipad i don't see the video.

How can I fix??

attaching Video code :

```
    package com.view.generic
{


import com.constants.Dimentions;

    import com.view.AbstractScreen;
    import com.view.IScreen;
    import com.view.gui.Btn;

    import flash.errors.IOError;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;

    import org.osflash.signals.natives.NativeSignal;

    public class VideoMode extends AbstractScreen implements IScreen
    {
        private var _player:Video;
        private var _stream:NetStream;
        public function VideoMode()
        {

        }
        override public function start():void{
            super.start();
            var conn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
            conn.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler)
            conn.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, netStatusError)
            conn.connect(null);
            layoutPlayer();
            layoutMenu();

        }

        override public function stop():void{
            _stream.pause();
        }



        private function layoutMenu():void{
            var playBtn:Btn = new Btn("video_play_button.png");
            addChild(playBtn);
            playBtn.x = (Dimentions.HEIGHT -playBtn.width)/2;
            playBtn.y = _player.y+_player.height+20;
            var clickSignal:NativeSignal = new NativeSignal(playBtn,MouseEvent.CLICK);
            clickSignal.add(play);

            var fullScrBtn:Btn = new Btn("full_screen.png");
            addChild(fullScrBtn);
            fullScrBtn.x = _player.width -fullScrBtn.width+_player.x;;
            fullScrBtn.y = _player.y+_player.height+20;
            var fullScrSignal:NativeSignal = new NativeSignal(fullScrBtn,MouseEvent.CLICK);
            fullScrSignal.add(goFullScreen);
        }

        private function layoutPlayer():void{
            _player.width = 400;
            _player.height = 300;
            _player.x = (Dimentions.HEIGHT -_player.width)/2;
            _player.y = 200;
            _stream.play("../../../assets/drum_ny.flv");
            _stream.pause();

        }

        private function goFullScreen(e:MouseEvent):void{
            if(_player.x == 0){
                layoutPlayer()
            }else{
                _player.x = 0;
                _player.y = 0;
                _player.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
                _player.height = stage.fullScreenHeight;
            }

        }
        private function play(e:MouseEvent):void{
            _stream.resume()
        }

        private function netStatusHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void{
            if(e.info.code=="NetConnection.Connect.Success"){
                _stream = new NetStream(NetConnection(e.target));
                _stream.client = this;
                _player = new Video();
                addChild(_player);

                _player.attachNetStream(_stream)

            }
        }
        private function netStatusError(e:IOError):void{
            trace(e)
        }

        override public function destroy():void{

        }
        public function onMetaData(info:Object):void {

        }

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check to make sure that the file will play on an iOS device w/o the Flash Player.  I know there are issues; but I don't know the extent.  Is H.264 supported on iOS in AIR for Android?

Comment: The issue was fixed after replacing the flv file , ,Thanks

Comment: Great!  Be sure to answer your own question and select it as such so folks know how you solved the issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by replacing the FLV file, however I am still not sure why one flv file works and the other does not.

If you encounter such a problem (video works on simulator but not on device) your first bet should be replacing the video source.

Comment: A relative path to ANY file doesn't work, your issue wasn't changing the flv sir.

Comment: well , I wish I had some way to prove it, i guess you will have to take my word for it. peace

Answer (score 2):

This is likely your problem :

```
 _stream.play("../../../assets/drum_ny.flv");
```

That file doesn't exist once you compile your app into a .ipa file.  Try changing that to a web address of somewhere you can upload it to and if it works, then that's your prob.

Comment: With a different flv file it works now, why would the compiler not pack the video into the .ipa ,,  thanks

Comment: You have to embed an asset if you want it to be packed as part of the app.  Giving it a relative path like this, that file DOESNT exist.